# What to do with an old sump well?

Tags: well, sump

I've recently found what appears to be an old sump well on my property. It's been buried by dirt and debris, but once that was cleared I now have a 22.5" diameter hole in the concrete that appears to be ~30" deep — which is why I'm assuming it's a sump well. We definitely get a lot of water on this side in the rainy seasons, but since owning the home we've found another approach to solving for excess water on this side.

Anyone have any suggestions on what to do with the hole? It's an odd size, so getting a cover is proving near impossible. Should I just fill it with concrete and move along?

Comment: Why wouldn't you just fill it with dirt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sure you will not need the sump fill and pack it with dirt until ~4” from the top then a few bags of sackcrete can be mixed up and poured so the floor is usable. Finishing a small area like his would not be hard and that would cover the hole.

Answer (score 0):

Leave it. Fill it with #4 crusher.

Turn it into a fountain.

Always easier to cap it, can handle a bit of overflow. Put a garden around it and make it the irrigation point.